# Android Studio--Flutter Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have just created a new flutter project and I cannot run it. In my old computer, I succesfully run the project, but in the new one I get;

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:85)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3527)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:77)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1022)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3454)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3447)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:592)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2376)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:461)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:172)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1017)
    ... 16 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried all the solution in stackoverflow, yet I could not solve it. New ideas will be appraciated.

Comment: Note: I did run flutter doctor and have no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

The error `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch` seems to be commonly caused by network issues as mentioned in this [issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63193). If you have cached pub dependencies, you can try running it offline with `flutter pub run --offline. Other than that, you can try restarting your machine or try a different network.